# differences between char * and string

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to know the differences between `char *` and `string`.
for example in this code:

```
char *a;
string b;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The cat can eat biscuit, biscuit can't eat a cat.

Comment: @SuvP In extreme cases, the biscuit can come to the cat.

Comment: @SuvP Do you know what's common between them?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Both can lie around doing nothing? (I hope you were not expecting nethin technical :P )

Comment: @SuvP No. They're both not a dinosaur.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Just like they are both not a bird? (Let's not pollute the thread further :P )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to `std::string`, `string` is a standard library class modelling a string.

char* is just a pointer to a single char. In C and C++, various functions exist that will take a pointer to a single char as a parameter and will track along the memory until a 0 memory value is reached (often called the *null terminator*). In that way it models a string of characters; `strlen` is an example of a function (from the C standard library) that does this.

If you have a choice, use `std::string` as you don't have to concern yourself with memory.

Comment: Since `string` is a class, which data-member of it, holds the text that we assign to string?

Answer (score 3):

`char*` is a pointer to a primitive type: `char`

`string` is a first class object from the Standard Template Library that wraps a lot of functionality (like concatenating two strings) and makes it easier to work with.

2 very different entities!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, `char *a;` declares a pointer 'a' of type `char`,it will point to a constant string or character arrays. `String b;` declares b as an object of `string` type.String here is a class which contains several string manipulation member functions(methods).You can look here for further details:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

One example program describing the `string` object and its member function is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("steve jobson");
  cout <<"hello the name of steve jobs consists of"<< str.size() << " characters.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

`str` is declared as string object and the member function `size()` is called to get the size of str.

Answer (score 0):

`char*` can also be a pointer to the 0 (first) place of an array of characters. It was used frequently in **C**, where the use of String is not supported.

Comment: if you declare char a pointer to an array of characters then your answer would be right but here its some thing else ,its a single character

Comment: even by being a single character, it is an array with one cell. *a refers to its value, while &a refers to its address within the memory.

Comment: i don't understand which array you are referring to, "logical" or "physical".

Answer (score 0):

if you are worrying about functionality, `string` is a **functional** `char*` i.e you need not to worry about `space`

**char***

declaration/initialization: `char* str = "Use";`

appending: `XXX`

finding length: `strlen(str);` //need to include `<string.h>` or create your own

**string**

declaration/initialization: `string str = "Use";`

appending: `str += " This!"`

finding length: `str.length()` //all in one header file